# Load list of roles for each user in MVC5 razor

Tags: c#, razor, sqlmembershipprovider, asp-net-mvc-1

I am trying to display a row of each user and their roles in the ASP.net MVC application.

Users and their roles are stored in ASP.net membership provider table. 
Using the code below I can display each user and the role they are assigned, but my problem is if the user is in multiple roles then the user gets repeated.

I tried making UserRole as List but I am now stuck as I do not know how to add the roles to a list in the code below. Could you please provide me some direction?

My viewmodel is :

```
public class UserViewModel
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public List<String> UserRole { get; set; }
}


var roles = ApplicationRoles.RolesList;
       var users = new List<UserViewModel>();
       foreach (var role in roles)
        {
           foreach (var user in Roles.GetUsersInRole(role)) 
            {
               users.Add(new UserViewModel {UserName = user, UserRole = role });
            }
        }

return View(users);
```

How can I load the roles so I do not repeat username if the user has multiple roles attached to him/her?

I would like to display it in the following format:

=======================

User  |  Role

John  | Admin, Approver

Sam   | Approver

=======================

Comment: Did you get this to work how you wanted? I used the selected answer, but my roles are blank, and I know I have users with roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you do like this

```
  foreach (var user in Roles.GetUsersInRole(role)) 
  {
      users.Add(new UserViewModel {UserName = user, NameAndRole = user + "|"+ String.Join(",", UserRole.ToArray() });
  }
```

or you can add property in your viewmodel class and use it

```
Public String NameAndRole
{
  get
   { return name + " | "+ String.Join(",", UserRole.ToArray()) }
}
```

MSDN : [String.Join](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F57a79xd0(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=LZOaVYruK5WouQTL7Ya4Cg&usg=AFQjCNGWavXSxM5Cw51FJN99okOq5Edwcg&sig2=CpUg98G5f1hlxlhgUwPBKA&bvm=bv.96952980,d.c2E)

Comment: Thank you @Pranay , but what happens if I have a user who have multiple roles? This will still repeat the user and I just want to display it only once.

Comment: @snowflakes74 - for that i just use string.join where there are multiple roles it will join and display

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way round: don't get users with a certain role, get the list of users and loop through that, using the `Roles.GetRolesForUser` method to get their list of rows.

```
var userList = Membership.GetAllUsers();

foreach(MembershipUser user in userList)
{
    string[] rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName); 
    users.Add(new UserViewModel {UserName = user.UserName, UserRole = string.Join(",", rolesArray) });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user1666620, I will try your logic, my pc is rebooting now.

Comment: I like this way better, however, the roles are always coming back empty. How can this be fixed?

Comment: BTW:  I had to enable `RoleManager` with `<roleManager enabled="true" />` in the `web.config`